# A question based on universal truth

Tags: phrase-choice

Choose the correct alternative

> Had we been alone we would have contented ourselves with any plain
>   food that give us strength
>   (1) that gives us strength
>
> (2) that gave us strength

According to the book, (1) is the right choice claiming that it's a universal truth. I think (2) is the right choice. I am confused over this, please help.

Comment: Also you should cite the source. Some learning materials have been known to be questionable.

Comment: I am really sorry.. I erroneously wrote the wrong question. Actually, acc. to the book (1) is the right answer.. but I believe (2) should be the right answer... @LucianSava I don't agree on your answer.. I don't think that makes much sense..

Answer (score 1):

Your example poses a question that is set in a distant hypothetical past. In fact we are not alone and we don't content ourselves with plain food.

Most of the time when we talk about conditions that would have affected our past actions, we say things like:

> I would have gone if I'd had transport.

Turning to your example, the only option that fits is:

> We would have contented ourselves with plain food that *gave* us strength.

or *would have given us strength* had we eaten it.

Because we didn't eat plain food and still don't, the situation doesn't hold true.

Alternatively, imagining that we were alone, you might write:

> Because we were alone, we (have) had to content ourselves with plain food that *gives* us strength.

That's to say, the situation holds true.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer as it's the way I, myself, would have answered the question. However there's a word in your answer I don't quite agree with : *distant*.

Comment: @LucianSava Although it's possible to interpret the O.P.'s phrase *had we been alone* in various ways, I took it to mean "had there not been other species" (whom we eat!) But I wouldn't argue its merits.